# MySQL explain filtered column jumping 4,100 with index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

My Query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT  `artwork`.`id` ,  `artwork`.`added` 
FROM  `artwork` 
ORDER BY  `artwork`.`added` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 6
```

When I added an index on "added" to avoid using `filesort` and use `index` instead the output of explained went from

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 SIMPLE artwork ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 302 100.00 Using filesort
```

to

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 SIMPLE artwork index NULL added 4 NULL 6 5033.33
```

and I'm concerned about the filtered going up approximently 4,100 - I can't find on Google what `filtered` means

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey, it's actually good news.  It shows how many rows your limitations are removing from the result set.  In this case, that would be your `LIMIT` statement.  [See the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html):

> The `filtered` column indicates an estimated percentage of table rows
>   that will be filtered by the table
>   condition. That is, `rows` shows the
>   estimated number of rows examined and
>   `rows` × `filtered` / 100 shows the number
>   of rows that will be joined with
>   previous tables. This column is
>   displayed if you use EXPLAIN EXTENDED.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying it's good, but I still don't quite understand what it means...

Comment: @Webnet It means that, without your `LIMIT` clause, `filtered`% __additional__ rows would be returned instead.  Try removing your `LIMIT` clause and you'll see the filtered number drop to 0 and the `rows` become the total number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 3):

From the [**docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html):

> `filtered`
>
> The `filtered` column indicates an estimated percentage of table rows that will be filtered by the table condition. That is, `rows` shows the estimated number of rows examined and `rows × filtered / 100` shows the number of rows that will be joined with previous tables. This column is displayed if you use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`. (New in MySQL 5.1.12)

Basically, it's ratio of records returned to records fetched.

Its goal is to show how selective your `WHERE` / `ON` conditions are and what would be the benefit of creating an index on them.

Note that this field has little sense for the queries with `LIMIT`, since it's always calculated without regard to the `LIMIT` clause, which `rows` is calculated with regard to the latter.