# Best way to get the latest 5 posts from a category?

Tags: php, mysql

I have setup my news script so it will display the latest 5 posts (from the same category as the currently viewed post - excluding the currently viewed post).

My SQL looks like this :

```
SELECT title, sid, url, category
FROM news 
WHERE category = ? AND sid <> ? ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 5
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for the query :

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys    | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | news     | ref  | PRIMARY,category | category | 98      | const |  154 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I'm wondering is - is there any way to optimize my query so it doesn't have to scan so many rows to get the 5 results?

EDIT

Results with Category Index :

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT title, sid, url, category FROM news WHERE category = ? AND sid <> ? ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: news
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,category
          key: category
      key_len: 98
          ref: const
         rows: 156
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Results *without* Category Index :

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT title, sid, url, category FROM news WHERE category = ? AND sid <> ? ORDER BY sid DESC LIMIT 5\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: news
         type: index
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 2
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5
     filtered: 7420.00
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

***Edit: This answer does not work***

Based on @Mayhem's comment below, specifying a column index in descending order does nothing, though *may* do something in the future.  This is even true in [version 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).  I think this is useful to keep this up because people might think using `DESC` actually does something.

**Original Answer**

If you create an index on `sid` in descending order (order is important), then that should be used in the ORDER BY clause and improve the results by a lot.

The create statement should look something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_news_category_sid
    ON news (category, sid DESC)
```

Comment: How do I use that index in the 'order by' clause?

Comment: The Query Optimizer will choose to use the index by itself, you don't have to specify anything.

Comment: The query optimizer still chooses the 'category' index over anything else. When I do a 'FORCE INDEX' (as a test), it now needs to scan over 300 rows using the new index.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue :/ (really appreciate the assistance though) - it still wants to use category index and when I use "FORCE INDEX", it needs to scan 150 rows.

Comment: Try this: `RESET QUERY CACHE;` run with the index, then do the reset again and remove the index and run again.  Whichever runs better, keep -- though the index might do better in long run.

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working : "An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order"

Comment: @Mayhem, according to some other SO answers, MySQL search the index in either direction, so this answer may actually work.  I think you might try having ***two indexes***, the one above, and one on just `sid`.  That might have the best result.

Comment: 'sid' has always been my primary index - still have the same results. There is no other solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you add the output to show warnings in your quesion?  Can show the output with an without the index, after reset query cache? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-extended.html

Comment: wow .. removing the category index solved all my issues. See edit in original question.

Comment: That sounds wrong.  I don't know exactly what filtered means, but to compare the two results I think you need to multiple rows by filtered.

Comment: The filtered column indicates an estimated percentage of table rows that will be filtered by the table condition. That is, rows shows the estimated number of rows examined and rows × filtered / 100 shows the number of rows that will be joined with previous tables. This column is displayed if you use EXPLAIN EXTENDED.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140107 - it would appear this is good news?

Comment: Lol.  I really want to figure this out, because you don't have previous tables to join to.  What is your primary key, and what indexes do you have with the second EXPLAIN?

Comment: My primary key is 'sid' - I do not have any other indexes with the second explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table for the latest ones. This comes pretty handy when you have more than 10 million rows. Simply create a trigger for the actual table for insert and delete so you will always have update records and only how much rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this website for `Table Indexing` this improves your search a lot.

The CREATE INDEX statement is used to create indexes in tables.
Indexes allow the database application to find data fast; without reading the whole table.

link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp